# CKModifyRecordsOperation completion block operates to early

Tags: cloudkit

I delete all records in a recordZone with

```
   CKModifyRecordsOperation *modifyRecordsOperation = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:nil recordIDsToDelete:[arrayWithRecordIdsMutable copy]];
```

The completionblock contains a method to read all records (just to check). As I would expect no records to be found, instead there are still "some" records left. If I read a few minutes later, they are gone.

I tried with

```
  modifyRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = ^(NSArray *records, NSArray *deletedRecordIDs, NSError *error) {
```

as well as with the "normal" completionBlock from NSOperations

```
  [modifyRecordsOperation setCompletionBlock:^{
```

still the same result. Does anyone have an idea, whether I'm doing something wrong and/or how to trigger activities directly after the delete did completely happened?

Apple docs says:
*If you assign a completion block to the completionBlock property of the operation object, the completion block is called after the operation executes and returns its results to you. You can use a completion block to perform housekeeping chores related to the operation, but do not use it to process the results of the operation itself. Any completion block you specify should be prepared to handle the failure of the operation to complete its task, whether due to an error or an explicit cancellation.*

I'm wondering what they mean with *but do not use it to process the results of the operation itself* 
May be this is a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is that all the records are marked as deleted but will eventually be deleted in a batch. I would recommend removing indexes you don't need to speed it up a bit. Also, the development environment is a *lot* slower than in production.

You'll see the same in the `CloutKit Dashboard`, select 20+ records and hit delete. Refresh and you'll still see some being deleted.